# SSH script using file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have been using the following script to remote into my systems:

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME=someUser
HOSTS="host1 host2 host3"
SCRIPT="pwd; ls"
for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
    ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME} "${SCRIPT}"
done
```

It is becoming tedious to fill in the HOSTS=

I would like to read the hosts from a text file.  How would I modify this script for that to work?

Thank you.

Comment: Please avoid using CAPS for shell variable names. This can lead to unexpected behavior since, by convention, global environment variables are in CAPS. For instance, there is the global `HOSTNAME` variable which you are overwriting in your loop and the global `USERNAME` variable (used by some systems). I doubt it is causing you issues here, but avoiding CAPS for variable names is a good habit to get into.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, and I will take it into consideration.  However, this doesn't contribute to the immediate challenge I am facing.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Which is why I left a comment about it (aimed not only at you but also at every other user who will see this) and posted an answer below with a working solution. And also why I specified that it isn't causing you issues here.

Comment: You are probably ready to start experimenting with ansible.

Comment: "Parallel Distribued Shell" aka [pdsh](https://github.com/chaos/pdsh) does what you want.  You can find questions and answers that mention [pdsh related answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=pdsh) here on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The modification is very simple. Assuming you have a file with one hostname per line, all you need is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
username=someUser
script="pwd; ls"
while read -r hostname; do
    ssh -n -l "$username" "$hostname" "$script"
done < "$1"
```

Then, run your script with the file as an argument:

```
script.sh /path/to/hosts/file
```

Note that I changed your variables to lower case. It is generally a bad idea to use CAPS for shell variables since by convention, global environment variables are capitalized and this can result in unexpected behavior because of name collision. This is double important when you're using standard variable names like `HOSTNAME` and `USERNAME` which are very often defined in the environment already.

Also, the `-n` option is needed here to stop `ssh` from trying to read the rest of the file. Without the `-n`, only the first iteration would work because the `ssh` command would consume the rest of its standard input and so end up reading the entire file.

Comment: Also `xargs -I {} ssh -n -l "$user" {} "$script" <"$1"` for the simple job of iterating over each line of some file.

Comment: There is also the `readarray` option, particularly useful in case the list of hosts was used more than once in the script.

Comment: Using what you defined in your script, I am receiving the following:

myuser@myhost:~/scripts$ ./servcheck.sh /home/myuser/scripts/hostfile.txt
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known

I have added several hosts this this file, each host name is an fqdn, and it is on its own line as such:

myremotehost1.mydomain.com
myremotehost2.mydomain.com
myremotehost3.mydomain.com

I verified my permissions for the host file are read/write.  I ran a pwd to validate my path to the hostfile.txt as well.

Suggestions?

Comment: @JasonH that's because I'm an idiot ;) I was using `hostname` in the `while` but `$host` in the `ssh` command. Please try updated answer, it should work as expected now.

Comment: it does, thank you. I also had to edit the username variable.

Comment: @steeldriver good point, thanks. That was actually an edit by Kusalananda, but it was absolutely a correct edit and without it the solution wouldn't work.